# Web Scraping with Scala

Tags: scala, web-scraping, libraries

Just wondering if anyone knows of a web-scraping library that takes advantage of Scala's succinct syntax. So far, I've found [Chafe](https://github.com/ofrasergreen/chafed), but this seems poorly-documented and maintained. I'm wondering if anyone out there has done scraping with Scala and has advice. (I'm trying to integrate into an existing Scala framework rather than use a scraper written in, say, Python.)

Comment: The scraper libs that somewhat worked for me are httpunit and htmlunit. But they're Java libraries and not explicitly Scala.

Comment: When faced with a similar challenge I found this [Scala HTML](http://www.hars.de/2009/01/html-as-xml-in-scala.html) library useful. It's a bit old, but still did the trick for me. I wrapped it with an SBT build [here](https://github.com/slevine/scalaxml).  HTH

Comment: Just to inform that I have written a pimped Jsoup: https://github.com/filosganga/ssoup

Comment: I've written a DSL to build scraping Akka actor systems, it uses JSoup and spray-client under the hood. The DSL provided manipulates an immutable context (inspired by spray-routing), it can found here: https://github.com/bfil/scalescrape

Comment: I really like this article showing how to do scraping with akka: http://foat.me/articles/crawling-with-akka/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First there is a plethora of HTML scraping libs in JVM all you need to do is [pimp one of them (pimp my library pattern)](http://www.decodified.com/scala/2010/12/02/the-quickpimp-pattern).

The four I have used are:

- HtmlUnit - Will emulate the browser and even run Javascript
- Jericho - Preserves formatting and ideal if you want to edit the scraped HTML
- NekoHtml
- JSoup -- <strike>[does not work with Scala](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3809)</strike>. [Might work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745634/web-scraping-with-scala/14759873#comment20659065_14759873)

I have used Selenium but never for scraping. [Scala has a wrapper around selenium](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium).

I would recommend pimping an existing Java library over some half baked Scala lib.

Comment: "half baked Scala" can be twice as good as "(over) baked java" though.

Comment: Well if its over baked yes. Nobody likes burnt cookies :) .... Then again you can't get salmonella from over baked cookies like you can from under baked cookies :) . Regardless I still think you should not play language bias particularly since Groovy, Scala, and Clojure are good at interacting with existing Java. Besides Java 8 is out so hopefully there will be less over baking.

Comment: These days there is also scala-scraper library which is a wrapper around JSoup. It brings quite convenient syntax for extracting data from html pages.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have a Scala-specific recommendation, but for the JVM in general I've had good success with:

- [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) You can CSS selectors to "scrape" the document.  Really nice to work with.
- Use [Tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to get your input HTML to XML, then use XML processors to "Scrape".

The Tagsoup route actually works quite well with Scala since Scala's built-in XML "dsl" is pretty concise (if you can forgive its perf issues and occasional API weirdness).  Also, Tagsoup will handle nearly any garbage document you give it.  It also has niceties like built-in understanding of many HTML entities that other SAXParsers will choke on as being undeclared.

**tl;dr** - JSoup + CSS selectors if possible, otherwise Tagsoup + scala XML. If slow is ok, tagsoup first, then jsoup the result.

Comment: FYI that last time I checked JSoup does not work with Scala: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3809

Comment: @AdamGent Weird.  I'm successfully using JSoup 1.7.1 in a project with scala 2.9.2.  It's possible my use of it doesn't trigger the issue (?)

Comment: Probably. We found this out the hard way and I no longer have the code. Actually sadly it was one of the many reasons we stopped using Scala :(

Comment: Looks like the JSoup author fixed the Scala issue a couple years back: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/54

Comment: Damn what a reminder of how long its been. If I remember correctly I don't even think Scala 2.9 was out when it happened.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Goose: https://github.com/jiminoc/goose

It's not as general-use as you might need but if you are scraping article content from popular sites, it may work out of the box. It also provides a framework for you to work from if you want to extend their code to cover other sites.