# Use case for WebDriver (https://github.com/typesafehub/webdriver) to execute js

Tags: scala, selenium, akka, spray

I'm working on a web scraper using this project (based on Scala, Spray, Akka and PhantomJS)

The problem is that I can't find a more specific example of how to use it, and the documentation is missing a lot of details

1- I would like to know how to give an specific URL so I can get data from it

2- How can I excecute, or pass a javascript file or function so that phantom can run and do some stuff(return specific data or whatever, from the site in point 1- )

Here is my Main.scala file: (Is almost the same as the one in the project)

```
package com.typesafe.webdriver.tester

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.pattern.ask

import com.typesafe.webdriver.{Session, PhantomJs, LocalBrowser}
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import spray.json._
import spray.http._



object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("webdriver-system")
     implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

     system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(7.seconds) {
      system.shutdown()
      System.exit(1)
     }
    val browser = system.actorOf(PhantomJs.props(system), "localBrowser")
    browser ! LocalBrowser.Startup
    for (
      session <- (browser ? LocalBrowser.CreateSession).mapTo[ActorRef];
      result <- (session ? Session.ExecuteNativeJs("return 5+5",JsArray(JsNumber(999)))).mapTo[JsNumber]
    ) yield {
       println(result)
      try {
       system.shutdown()
       System.exit(0)
      } catch {
        case _: Throwable =>
        }

     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use already created web scrappers in Scala.
For example ScalaWebDcraper which has nicely writted DSL and scrapping feature.

https://github.com/Rovak/ScalaWebscraper

It can be combined with Goose, which is a web article extractor. You can use it to fetch article data from the links you visit with the previous library.

https://github.com/jiminoc/goose

Also, checkout Metascrapper, a Scala Library for Scraping Page Metadata

https://beachape.com/blog/2013/09/05/introducing-metascraper-a-scala-library-for-scraping-page-metadata/

And check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745634/web-scraping-with-scala), lot's of valuable info inside.